# Cannot join objects(tables) names using database_id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I cannot find a way to join objects using the `database_id`.

I am trying to write an audit query which scans through the tables by accepting the database name as parameter.

**I want to avoid dynamic queries**.
**Is it possible?**

like

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.tables a
       JOIN sys.tables b
         ON a.datbase_id = b.database_id
            AND b.database_name = 'testdb'
```

Comment: You need to specify the db name *before* the system view name, e.g. like `JOIN testdb.sys.tables`, so that you actually access the system view from the required database. I don't think this is possible without dynamic sql.

Comment: I'm afraid to tell you that it's not possible doing this without dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go.

```
select * 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES it
    inner join sys.tables st
        on st.name = it.table_name
where it.TABLE_CATALOG = 'testdb'
```

Comment: The where condition does not have any role to play since the "TABLE_CATALOG" is the same value of the database connected in the session.So this may be wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Recursive... I wasn't really thinking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such column as `database_id` in `information_schema.tables`. Secondly there is an undocumented stored proc called `sp_msForEachDb`, which iterates through all the database one by one and runs the script that you want to, which you need to pass as a string input to it.

In your case, it seems that you want to join the `information_schema.tables` with `sys.tables` and list the tables for `testDB` database. Try the script below for that:

```
--Build a temp table to store the info
select * into  #a 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES it join sys.tables st 
on st.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS= it.table_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
where 1=0

insert into #a --This script runs for each database and populates the info into #a
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES it join [?].sys.tables st 
on st.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS= it.table_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
where it.TABLE_CATALOG = ''testdb'''

select * from #a
```